# Wait till user closes another application Opened by WPF in WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a method which is working good when Run in CONSOLE application but when run this in WPF on button click it opens application but doesn't wait till uses closes application.

```
        private static int OpenApplication(string applicationName)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = applicationName,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                };
                Process p = Process.Start(psi);
                if (p != null)
                {
                    
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    if (p.ExitCode == 0)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return 1;
        }
```

What should I do to execute a function when user closes application in WPF? this is not waiting as I am trying in button click event

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = OpenApplication("appicationFileName");
            if (x == 0)
            {
                msg.Content = "Exited";
            }
            else
            {
                msg.Content = "Waiting";
            }

        }
```

This worked well in Console app.

Comment: tried with `UseShellExecute = false` ?

Comment: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform Error will come and it will not work. Thanks for this comment

Comment: Is it showing an error via MessageBox.Show() at all? Have you tried setting a break point on p.WaitForExit(); and stepping through the code?

Comment: Also, on your Button_Click, you have 'async', but you have no 'await' call. Maybe you need to do `var x = await OpenUsersAndGroup("appicationFileName");`. Not sure if you meant to change the name, but the OpenUsersAndGroup method (which isn't shown if it is different) should have a signature like `private static Task<int> OpenUsersAndGroup(string applicationName)`

Comment: That I tried but not working as Main Thread assumes process is ended and not part of main thread.

Comment: I tried it, assuming that OpenUsersAndGroup is actually OpenApplication in your posted code, and it works (I started notepad.exe). You need to give some more information on exactly what you are doing for us to be able to help you. 
And you should probably refactor to keep the UI responsive while waiting for the external application, but that can be the next step.

Comment: I want to open any application like notepad and want to wait till user closes that notepad.

Comment: This works well and wait till user closes application if file name is notepad.exe but in case of lusrmgr.msc it is exiting just after starting the process.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. lusrmgr.msc/mmc.exe ignores the ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden though.